# Can you answer xampp for linux installation qustions via Dockerfile

Tags: docker, xampp

Am trying to build a Docker image for xampp linux.
Is it possible to pass the answers to xampp's installations questions via a Dockerfile ? Running the xampp installer starts the wizard below;

```
> Welcome to the XAMPP Setup Wizard.
> 
> XAMPP Core Files : Y (Cannot be edited) XAMPP Developer Files [Y/n] :Y
> Is the selection above correct? [Y/n]: Y Installation Directory XAMPP
> will be installed to /opt/lampp Press [Enter] to continue: Setup is
> now ready to begin installing XAMPP on your computer. Do you want to
> continue? [Y/n]: Y
```

> ```
> Press Enter to Continue
> ```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04 
RUN apt-get update \ && apt-get install wget -yq \
 && wget apachefriends.org/xampp-files/7.1.11/… \ 
 && mv /root/xampp-linux-x64-7.1.11-0-installer.run /opt/ \ 
 && cd /opt/ \ && chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-7.1.11-0-installer.run \ 
 && ./xampp-linux-x64-7.1.11-0-installer.run 

EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: can you post ur Dockerfile?

Comment: FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install wget -yq \
 && wget https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/7.1.11/xampp-linux-x64-7.1.11-0-installer.run \
 && mv /root/xampp-linux-x64-7.1.11-0-installer.run /opt/ \
 && cd /opt/ \
 && chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-7.1.11-0-installer.run \
 && ./xampp-linux-x64-7.1.11-0-installer.run


EXPOSE 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a Solution is

printf 'y\n\y\nr\n\y\n\r\n' | ./xampp-linux-x64-7.1.11-0-installer.run

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the command `./xampp-linux-x64-7.1.11-0-installer.run` is asking for input. You can use a small shell trick:

```
&& yes | ./xampp-linux-x64-7.1.11-0-installer.run
```

This will input `y` to the installer.

Comment: what about the final carriage return

Comment: @PaddyPopeye just change `&& ./xampp-linux-x64-7.1.11-0-installer.run` to `&& yes |  ./xampp-linux-x64-7.1.11-0-installer.run `

Comment: doing only that results in ... returned a non-zero code: 1... is not handling the final required carriage return

Comment: @PaddyPopeye are there an more useful error messages

Comment: your method will not work as passing yes when a "\r" is what is needed throws an error, as when i tested... One solution is " && printf 'y\n\y\nr\n\y\n\r\n' | ./xampp-linux-x64-7.1.11-0-installer.run " .... bit of a sloppy hack but working